# Create Unmanaged<CFString> from Swift

Tags: swift, memory, memory-management, interop, automatic-ref-counting

Since Swift 2, C functions that take C callbacks can be invoked from Swift without an intermediate wrapper.

Many C event handling APIs follow the pattern that you first create a context:

```
struct Context {
    CFIndex version;
    void *info;
    CFAllocatorRetainCallBack retain;
    CFAllocatorReleaseCallBack release;
    CFAllocatorCopyDescriptionCallBack copyDescription;
}
```

The context is then passed to the C API when registering our callback. When an event received, the info pointer is passed with the event to the callback function, allowing us to restore contextual state (as C functions don't allow state being captured).

I would like to properly create such a context, including the `retain`, `release` and `copyDescription` callbacks.

For copyDescription, the signature is

```
typealias CFAllocatorCopyDescriptionCallBack = 
    (UnsafePointer<Void>) -> Unmanaged<CFString>!
```

How can I create an `Unmanaged<CFString>!` instance from Swift, i.e. how can I transfer a Swift string object out of the ARC memory model into an externally managed model?

Comment: to properly answer you question some need more information. Unmanaged is struct for propagating an unmanaged object reference. i recommend you to check http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/type/Unmanaged/ what it means exactly and how to use it. generally you can perform unbalanced retain or unbalanced release of the object, depends on your needs

Comment: Given that the name of the callback includes "Copy", I assume that I have to use passRetained: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#method-families

Comment: Unmanaged.passRetained looks like the answer :) Thanks! <3 If you repost as answer, I can accept it.

Comment: you are welcome! I am not vote eater :-) i am happy i could help you ...

Answer (score 1):

See question comments.

```
let string = Unmanaged.passRetained("description")
```